# Anonymus functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign an onclick event to the buttons which are created dynamically. The funtion is named myFunction and all the buttons call her but with differents argument. So I must use an anonymus function to assign the function. 
The problem is the assignment doesn't work. When I press any buton it calls the right function but with the last argument assigned.

html:

```
<div id="tbodyHT"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var contenu = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    contenu = contenu + "<a href='#' class='button small green' id='btndltHT" + i + "'></a><br/>";
}

document.getElementById('tbodyHT').innerHTML = contenu;

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    document.getElementById('btndltHT' + i).onclick = function() { alert(i) };
}
```

[code in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/katheosmu/d2cg2rjw/2/), but it doesn't work because I don't know how to handle this site.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a common gotcha, the answers in this question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Also, instead of generating so many functions, why not use one named function and pass a parameter. `contenu += "<a href='#' class='button small green' id='btndltHT" + i + "' onclick='doIt(" + i + "); return false'>button " + i + "</a><br/>";`

Comment: I did a working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/d2cg2rjw/5/